# Package visibility like Java in vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, visibility

Is there any way to set the method/class visibility as something like java's package visibility in vb.net?

The idea is that this method/class should be visible for classes on the same folder/package but not visible for classes outside this folder/package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge the closest thing to package in java in .net would be a namespace. But in .net there is no way to restrict access to types on level of namespaces if those exist in the same assembly. The only way to achieve this is to create class library and on this level you can manage visibility of classes between them by setting internal (default) or public access modifier. For more info read [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).